# Monotouch - iphone HttpWebRequest turn off caching?

Tags: iphone, caching, mono, httpwebrequest, xamarin.ios

I'm using monotouch for creating a iphone applicant which called a unsure page which returns JSON.

Strange one this... but when I use HttpWebRequest the output I receive is cached from an earlier request.

I timed it using a stop watch and I have to wait **two minutes** before I get a new version of the page up until this point every time I call HttpWebRequest I get output thats been cached.

Even if I kill the app and reload it the output is still the same for that two minute window.

This happens on both the simulator and the phone.

I've just tried adding a cache policy and no joy - I'm still getting all responses cached for 2 minutes.

heres my latests code:

```
Uri address = new Uri(url);
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy c = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy();
c.Level = RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore;
request.CachePolicy  = c;
request.Timeout = Settings.RequestTimeout;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Any one have any ideas?

Comment: this is freaking me out.  I just added a unique parameter to the url  i.e.   url + "&bypasscache"+DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();   which equates to &noCache=634331926598503290  so every url call by httpWebRequest is unique and it still caching it!!!!!

Comment: The last time I looked into this (a few months ago) it didn't appear that MT's HTTPWebRequest was doing any caching.  I suspect that there is some other mechanism (possibly server side caching) that is causing this.  Unless something has changed in MT I'm not aware of.

Comment: I did read up a little while ago that Safari caches objects under 25k which my page is.

Comment: Also I'm thinking this is an issue in general as If I invoke (on my MAC) the Add url through safari and then the obtain url my change doesnt show up for 2 mins.  If I do this with chrome on my MAC its instant.

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI, but Mono's HttpWebRequest implementation doesn't do any caching (yet). It may be implemented in the future, but as of 2.10.3 it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the request to a different address? Could it be caching the response server side for two minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the iOS related objects and methods. Seeing the caching is definitely implemented when using NSUrlCache in MonoTouch, and you can bypass it with the right NSUrlRequestCachePolicy enum. Here is how I did it when I wanted to avoid hitting the cache:

```
NSUrl url = new NSUrl (url);
NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest (url, 
                                 NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData, 
                                 0.0);

//set a delegate to handle the request callback, subclass this yourself
_webView.Delegate = new UIWebViewDelegate();
_webView.LoadRequest (request);
```

Hope this helps.