# HTTP caching in RestSharp (monotouch)

Tags: http, caching, proxy, xamarin.ios, restsharp

RestSharp (monotouch) seems to disregard the Cache-Control headers replied by the server (for GET calls). Is that the general case, that RestSharp doesn't perform proper HTTP caching? Or have I missed something? The following header params are used, but the document is not cached.

```
Date: Tue, 21 May 2013 11:34:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-transform, max-age=3600
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

If RestSharp itself doesn't support correct caching, how is local HTTP caching best implemented together with RestSharp? Adding a caching proxy component?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, and I was looking for an answer when I stumbled over this: [Monotouch - iphone HttpWebRequest turn off caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983782/monotouch-iphone-httpwebrequest-turn-off-caching#6958466)

Now since RestSharp is using HttpWebRequest under the hood, and the implementation of HttpWebRequest in monotouch doesn't feature caching, caching won't work in RestSharp either. So you (and I) have to implement our own caching component.

Comment: A nice place to start may be to use the LRU cache in MonoTouch.Dialog, written by Miguel DeIcaza. It's being used for image caching, but I'm sure it could be repurposed for HTTP responses with a little work.